# How to deserialize an object based on a text property using Newtonsoft

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

**JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)**

Is returning a set null objects. I've tried making the objects not descendants of *Widget*. Then I'm getting an error

> The value "Widget2" is not of type "Widget" and cannot be used in this generic collection. (Parameter 'value')

There's a lot of code in this question. What we're trying to do is deserialize a list of objects that have a text propery that tells us what the object should be deserialized as.

```cs
public class widgets
{
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(WidgetConverter))]
public class Widget
{
    public string widgetType { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Widget2 : Widget
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Widget3 : Widget
{
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types = (new List<Type> { typeof(Widget), typeof(Widget), typeof(Widget2), typeof(Widget3) }).ToArray();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var widgetType = obj.GetValue("WidgetType", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>().ToLower();
            switch (widgetType)
            {
                case "widget2":
                    var textWidget = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Widget2));
                    return textWidget;
                case "widget3":
                    var datavizWidget = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Widget3));
                    return datavizWidget;
                default:
                    var widget = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Widget));
                    return widget;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == typeToConvert);
    }
}
```

This is value of the string *json*

```js
{ "widgets": 
    [
        {
            "widgetType": "widget2",
            "name": "Widget type 2",
            "text": "Something is happening"
        },
        {
            "widgetType": "widget3",
            "name": "Widget type 3",
            "sourceId": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the class names according to your json string, after this you can use this converter

```
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<widgets>(json);

public class widgets
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(WidgetConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}

public class Widget
{
    public string widgetType
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class widget2 : Widget
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class widget3 : Widget
{
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
}
```

converter

```
public class WidgetConverter : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<Widget>>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Widget> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IEnumerable<Widget> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var a = JArray.Load(reader);

        return a.Select(o => (Widget)JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject(o.ToString(), Type.GetType((string)o["widgetType"]))).ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable<Widget> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```